# SAS Unable to write nzlog/bad files Netezza

Tags: sas, netezza

I am using SAS to load a table to the database. My code looks like this:

```
libname myLib "path\to\SASTable
libname con odbc noprompt="server=xxxx; DRIVER={NetezzaSQL}; port=xxxx; database=xxxxx; username=xxx; password=xxxx;";

proc sql;
   create table con.myTable
   (DBCREATE_TABLE_OPTS='distribute on (col1)' bulkload= YES)
   AS SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM myLib.mySASTable
quit;
```

When I run this, I get the error:

**ERROR: Error terminating Netezza load; Unable to write nzlog/bad files**

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: how large your SAS table is, if your sas table is small then do not use bulkload. what are the properties of ol1, col2, col3, col4, col5

Comment: @Kiran my table is just over 7 million records with 13 columns which are either numeric or characters. I would like to take advantage of bulkload

Comment: any date columns

Comment: @Kiran there are not any date columns. There are columns that have only a period as the value stored as a numeric. The reason why it's a numeric is because it's either a number or a period as the value...could that be the issue?

Comment: ya. trhat may be

Comment: @Kiran maybe not because I just realized that the other tables I loaded successfully had the same situation

Comment: @Kiran I also get the error when trying to load only one of the columns that always contains a value of type character

Comment: try without bulkload. this is not lot of data see heck your log file what is causing eroor and  an example below.proc sql;
create table net_air.flights98
       (bulkload=YES bl_options='logdir "c:\temp\netlogs"') 
        as select * from sasflt.flt98;
quit;

Comment: @Kiran thanks, I guess I had to specify the `bl_options` for logging

Comment: if it has work out, I will make that as answer, so that it can help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unable to write nzlog/bad files** looks like log file is not there to write errors/log of bulkload and can be created using bl_options in sas dataset options. An example of same is shown from below link

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=n119slgt394onmn12yd81pyytvin.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

```
 libname sasflt 'SAS-library';
 libname net_air netezza user=myuser pwd=mypwd
    server=air2 database=flights;

proc sql;
create table net_air.flights98
   (bulkload=YES bl_options="logdir 'c:\temp\netlogs'")
    as select * from sasflt.flt98;
 quit;
```